# Error: sv/gamma are too large

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I got this error with monero-wallet-rpc when trying to send 16 addresses monero with monero-pool.

```
2021-09-01 22:57:34.147 E sv/gamma are too large
```

When I tried to manually send the transaction in the monero-gui wallet I got the same error.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update Monero to the latest release (v0.17.2.3). There was a bug before this release with [transfer_split](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer_split).